# 'Model' object is not iterable

Tags: python, django

In author model:

```
century = models.ManyToManyField(Century)
```

In view:

```
a = get_object_or_404(Author.objects, id=id)

s = Author.objects.filter(century__in=a).order_by('?')[:3]
```

Error:

> Exception Value:   'Author' object is not iterable

What's wrong? The author may belong to two centuries and I want to get 3 random authors from his century/centuries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
a = get_object_or_404(Author.objects, id=id)

s = Author.objects.filter(century__in=a.century.all()).order_by('?')[:3]
```

Answer (score 3):

[`get_object_or_404()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) takes a *class* as the first arg. e.g.

`a = get_object_or_404(Author, id=id)`

**Update for comment:**

It's not mentioned anywhere in the docs, but you are correct. In fact, looking at the code (`django/shortcuts/__init__.py`) shows that that `get_object_or_404()` and `get_list_or_404()` can both take a Model, a Manager, or a QuerySet for their first arg.

Huh. You learn something every day!